# Launch Apps/Game Inside CE Form (Windows Form)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, lua, cheat-engine

I made a small VB Net project by follows a tutorial to open the windows app inside a form boundaries.
I have translated the functions to control windows app to Cheat Engine Lua syntax:

```
f = createForm()
f.setSize(640,500)
f.Caption = 'Test Apps Inside The Boundaries'

b = createButton(f)
b.setPosition(570,460)
b.setSize(60,30)
b.Caption = 'Launch'

function SetParent(hWndChild, hWndNewParent)
  executeCodeLocalEx('SetParent', hWndChild, hWndNewParent)
end

function SetWindowPos(hwnd, hWndInsertAfter, x, y, cx, cy, wFlags)
  executeCodeLocalEx('SetWindowPos', hwnd, hWndInsertAfter, x, y, cx, cy, wFlags)
end

function MoveWindow(hwnd, x, y, cx, cy, repaint)
  local rp
  if repaint then
    rp=1
  else
    rp=0
  end
  executeCodeLocalEx('MoveWindow', hwnd, x, y, cx, cy, rp)
end

function launch()
 local ps1 = os.execute'calculator.exe'
 sleep(1000)
 --- appWin1 = ps1.MainWindowHandle   --- how this?
 local appWin1 = findWindow(nil,'Calculator')
 SetParent(appWin1,f)
 MoveWindow(appWin1, 0,0, f.Width/2, f.Height/2,true)
end

b.OnClick = launch
```

But the code above didn't work. The code in VB Net is below:

```
NeedtoCELua = [[ Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
            Try
                Dim ps1 As New ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe")
                ps1.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
                Dim p1 As Process = Process.Start(ps1)
                Thread.Sleep(1000) ' Allow the process to open it's window
                appWin1 = p1.MainWindowHandle
                ' Put it into this form
                SetParent(appWin1, Me.Handle)
                ' Move the window to overlay it on this window
                MoveWindow(appWin1, 0, 0, Me.Width \ 2, Me.Height, True)

Private Sub Form8_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            If Me.appWin1 <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                MoveWindow(appWin1, 0, 0, Me.Width \ 2, Me.Height, True)
            End If

            If Me.appWin2 <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                MoveWindow(appWin2, Me.Width \ 2, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height, True)
            End If
            'base.OnResize(e);
        End Sub
]]
```

How to write a proper function in CE Lua refer to VB Net function for button click as shown above and make it work?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
function launch()
 ps1 = 'start notepad.exe'
 p1 = os.execute(ps1)
 sleep(1000)
 openProcess('notepad.exe')
 w=getWindow(getForegroundWindow(), GW_HWNDFIRST)
 pid=getOpenedProcessID()
   while w and (w~=0) do
     if (getWindowProcessID(w)==pid) and (executeCodeLocal("IsWindowVisible",w)~=0) then
       --print(w..' - '..getWindowCaption(w)..'('..getWindowClassName(w)..')')
     SetParent(w, f.handle)
     MoveWindow(w, 10, 20, 400, f.Height-100, 1)
     end
     w=getWindow(w, GW_HWNDNEXT)
   end
end

b.OnClick = launch
```